# debugging c with valgrind, invalid write/read of size 4

Tags: c, valgrind

I've read some of the posts about valgrind, but I still cannot figure out on my own.

So I have a C script which originally works just fine. I modified it later with some new inputs, and then I got a segmentation fault in one of my major for loops.

I actually located the error with some printf function, and I did some experiments to figure out which exact line caused the error. But none of those lines in the location I found matters the segmentation fault. I also double checked my malloc functions and my pointers, even though they work in the original version.

Then I read some posts about valgrind, and here is what I get:

```
==21733== Invalid write of size 4
==21733==    at 0x4014A4: h_spin_vor_amp (in /mnt/scratch-            
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403104: h_spin_shellwriter (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403A2C: main (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==  Address 0x11c27208 is 0 bytes after a block of size 
209,584,584 alloc'd
==21733==    at 0x4C27A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==21733==    by 0x402954: h_spin_shellwriter (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403A2C: main (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733== 
==21733== Invalid write of size 4
==21733==    at 0x4014E9: h_spin_vor_amp (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403104: h_spin_shellwriter (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403A2C: main (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==  Address 0x1e408208 is 0 bytes after a block of size 
209,584,584 alloc'd
==21733==    at 0x4C27A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==21733==    by 0x40297F: h_spin_shellwriter (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403A2C: main (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733== 
==21733== Invalid write of size 4
==21733==    at 0x40152E: h_spin_vor_amp (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403104: h_spin_shellwriter (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403A2C: main (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==  Address 0x2abe9208 is 0 bytes after a block of size 
209,584,584 alloc'd
==21733==    at 0x4C27A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==21733==    by 0x4029AA: h_spin_shellwriter (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403A2C: main (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733== 
==21733== Invalid write of size 4
==21733==    at 0x401573: h_spin_vor_amp (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403104: h_spin_shellwriter (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403A2C: main (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==  Address 0x373ca208 is 0 bytes after a block of size 
209,584,584 alloc'd
==21733==    at 0x4C27A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==21733==    by 0x4029D5: h_spin_shellwriter (in /mnt/scratch-lus 
tre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403A2C: main (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733== 
test0 test1 test2 test3 test4 
4475
test0 test1 test2 test3 test4 
4476
==21733== Invalid read of size 4
==21733==    at 0x400A30: h_spin_vor_amp (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403104: h_spin_shellwriter (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403A2C: main (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==  Address 0xffffffff34cc3cdc is not stack'd, malloc'd or (r 
ecently) free'd
==21733== 
==21733== 
==21733== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 
(SIGSEGV)
==21733==  Access not within mapped region at address 
0xFFFFFFFF34CC3CDC
==21733==    at 0x400A30: h_spin_vor_amp (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403104: h_spin_shellwriter (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403A2C: main (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==21733==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==21733==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==21733==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==21733==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.
==21733== Invalid read of size 4
==21733==    at 0x5126D7F: _IO_flush_all_lockp (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==21733==    by 0x5127C5E: _IO_cleanup (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==21733==    by 0x51F3E62: __libc_freeres (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==21733==    by 0x4A2266D: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:62)
==21733==    by 0x7FEFFF0C7: ???
==21733==    by 0x403104: h_spin_shellwriter (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403A2C: main (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==  Address 0xc2c80000c2c800c0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or 
(recently) free'd
==21733== 
==21733== 
==21733== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==21733==  General Protection Fault
==21733==    at 0x5126D7F: _IO_flush_all_lockp (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==21733==    by 0x5127C5E: _IO_cleanup (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==21733==    by 0x51F3E62: __libc_freeres (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==21733==    by 0x4A2266D: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:62)
==21733==    by 0x7FEFFF0C7: ???
==21733==    by 0x403104: h_spin_shellwriter (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403A2C: main (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733== 
==21733== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21733==     in use at exit: 16,767,087,832 bytes in 30 blocks
==21733==   total heap usage: 30 allocs, 0 frees, 16,767,087,832 bytes 
allocated
==21733== 
==21733== LEAK SUMMARY:
==21733==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21733==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21733==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21733==    still reachable: 16,767,087,832 bytes in 30 blocks
==21733==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21733== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==21733== 
==21733== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==21733== ERROR SUMMARY: 218519 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 6 
from 6)
```

Thanks!

## =========edit===========

Thanks for your suggestion, now I upload my code at below. What this code does is to read some simulation data processed by my python code. What I have is a simulation box with dimension (512,512,512). There is something called halos and morphologies(such as SFS) inside. Halos have spins, morphologies have vorticity, I want to know for a shell around the halo, what are the cosine between spins and vorticity. In addition, I want to know the relation between cosines and amplitudes of spins of halos.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define ArrayAccess2D_n2(a, n1, n2, i1, i2) (a)[ i2+n2*i1 ]
#define ArrayAccess3D_n3(a, n1, n2, n3, i, j, k) ((a)[ ((n2)*(i)+(j))*(n3)+(k) ])
#define ArrayAccess4D_n4(a, n1, n2, n3, n4, i1, i2, i3, i4) ((a)[ i4+n4*(i3+n3*(i2+n2*i1)) ])
#define ArrayAccess5D_n5(a, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5) ((a)[ i5+n5*(i4+n4*(i3+n3*(i2+n2*i1))) ])
#define dotproduct(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2) (x1*x2 + y1*y2 + z1*z2)
                

//cos between vec (x1, y1, z1) and (x2, y2, z2)
//if there is zero vector, set impossible value -100
float veccos(float x1, float y1, float z1, float x2, float y2, float z2)
{
    float cos, dot1, dot2;
    dot1 = dotproduct(x1, y1, z1, x1, y1, z1);
    dot2 = dotproduct(x2, y2, z2, x2, y2, z2);
    
    if(dot1!=0 && dot2!=0){
        cos = dotproduct(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2)/(sqrt(dot1)*sqrt(dot2));
    }
    else{
        cos = -100;
    }
    return cos;
}

//omega in py is (4,3,ng,ng,ng) array with padding, in order sfs, sfc, ufs, ufc
//halo_spin shape (3,ng,ng,ng) with padding
//halo_g of (3, halo_num), halo_R of (halo_num,) in unit of grids
void h_spin_vor_amp(float *halo_spinlist, int *halo_spinamp, int *halo_g, float *halo_R, float *omega, int halo_start, int halo_end, int halo_num, int ng, float Lbox, int lowbound_fac, int bound_fac, int padding, int ngp, float *out_sfs, float *out_sfc, float *out_ufs, float *out_ufc)
{
    long long iter=0;
    int g_x, g_y, g_z, g_R; //coordinator on grids
    int halo_x1, halo_x2, halo_y1, halo_y2, halo_z1, halo_z2;
    int ext_x1, ext_x2, ext_y1, ext_y2, ext_z1, ext_z2;
    float phy_R, h_sx, h_sy, h_sz;
    int i, j;

    //temporary array, recording cos of each type
        float *cos_sfst, *cos_sfct, *cos_ufst, *cos_ufct;
        cos_sfst = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float));
        cos_sfct = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float));
        cos_ufst = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float));
        cos_ufct = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float));

    for(long j=halo_start; j<halo_end; j++){
        printf("%d\n", j);

        int i;
        i=halo_spinamp[j];

                printf("test0 ");
        g_x = ArrayAccess2D_n2(halo_g, 3, halo_num, 0, i);
                g_y = ArrayAccess2D_n2(halo_g, 3, halo_num, 1, i);
                g_z = ArrayAccess2D_n2(halo_g, 3, halo_num, 2, i);

        phy_R = halo_R[i];
        g_R = phy_R*ng/(1000*Lbox);

        if( (phy_R*ng/(1000*Lbox) - g_R) > 0.5){
            g_R += 1;
        }

                halo_x1 = g_x - lowbound_fac*g_R; //boundary of halo edges
                halo_x2 = g_x + lowbound_fac*g_R;

                halo_y1 = g_y - lowbound_fac*g_R; //e.g. y1 < y2
                halo_y2 = g_y + lowbound_fac*g_R;

                halo_z1 = g_z - lowbound_fac*g_R;
                halo_z2 = g_z + lowbound_fac*g_R;

                ext_x1 = g_x - bound_fac*g_R; //boundary of extended edges
                ext_x2 = g_x + bound_fac*g_R;

                ext_y1 = g_y - bound_fac*g_R;
                ext_y2 = g_y + bound_fac*g_R;

                ext_z1 = g_z - bound_fac*g_R;
                ext_z2 = g_z + bound_fac*g_R;
                printf("test1 ");
        //compute cos of all in boundary
        for(long x=ext_x1+padding-1; x<ext_x2+padding; x++){
         for(long y=ext_y1+padding-1; y<ext_y2+padding; y++){
          for(long z=ext_z1+padding-1; z<ext_z2+padding; z++){

                        h_sx = ArrayAccess2D_n2(halo_spinlist, 3, halo_num, 0, i);
                        h_sy = ArrayAccess2D_n2(halo_spinlist, 3, halo_num, 1, i);
                        h_sz = ArrayAccess2D_n2(halo_spinlist, 3, halo_num, 2, i);

            cos_sfst[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z] = veccos(ArrayAccess5D_n5(omega, 4, 3, ngp, ngp, ngp, 0, 0, x,y,z), ArrayAccess5D_n5(omega, 4, 3, ngp, ngp, ngp, 0, 1, x,y,z), ArrayAccess5D_n5(omega, 4, 3, ngp, ngp, ngp, 0, 2, x,y,z), h_sx, h_sy, h_sz);

                    cos_sfct[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z] = veccos(ArrayAccess5D_n5(omega, 4, 3, ngp, ngp, ngp, 1, 0, x,y,z), ArrayAccess5D_n5(omega, 4, 3, ngp, ngp, ngp, 1, 1, x,y,z), ArrayAccess5D_n5(omega, 4, 3, ngp, ngp, ngp, 1, 2, x,y,z), h_sx, h_sy, h_sz); 

                    cos_ufst[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z] = veccos(ArrayAccess5D_n5(omega, 4, 3, ngp, ngp, ngp, 2, 0, x,y,z), ArrayAccess5D_n5(omega, 4, 3, ngp, ngp, ngp, 2, 1, x,y,z), ArrayAccess5D_n5(omega, 4, 3, ngp, ngp, ngp, 2, 2, x,y,z), h_sx, h_sy, h_sz);
 
                    cos_ufct[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z] = veccos(ArrayAccess5D_n5(omega, 4, 3, ngp, ngp, ngp, 3, 0, x,y,z), ArrayAccess5D_n5(omega, 4, 3, ngp, ngp, ngp, 3, 1, x,y,z), ArrayAccess5D_n5(omega, 4, 3, ngp, ngp, ngp, 3, 2, x,y,z), h_sx, h_sy, h_sz);
          }
         }
        }
                printf("test2 ");
        //set all cos in halo to invalid identifier -100
                for(int x=halo_x1+padding-1; x<halo_x2+padding; x++){
                 for(int y=halo_y1+padding-1; y<halo_y2+padding; y++){
                  for(int z=halo_z1+padding-1; z<halo_z2+padding; z++){
                    cos_sfst[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z] = -100;
                    cos_sfct[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z] = -100;
                    cos_ufst[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z] = -100;
                    cos_ufct[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z] = -100;
                  }
                 }
                }
                printf("test3 ");
        //recording cos
                for(int x=ext_x1+padding-1; x<ext_x2+padding; x++){
                 for(int y=ext_y1+padding-1; y<ext_y2+padding; y++){
                  for(int z=ext_z1+padding-1; z<ext_z2+padding; z++){

            out_sfs[iter] = cos_sfst[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z];
            out_sfc[iter] = cos_sfct[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z];
                    out_ufs[iter] = cos_ufst[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z];
                    out_ufc[iter] = cos_ufct[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z];
                        
                        cos_sfst[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z] = 0;
                        cos_sfct[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z] = 0;
                        cos_ufst[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z] = 0;
                        cos_ufct[(ngp*x + y)*ngp + z] = 0;

            iter++;
          }
         }
        }
                printf("test4 \n");
    }
    printf("iterate upto %lli \n", iter);
}

void h_spin_shellwriter(float Lbox, int ng, long ngp, char *sim_num, char *sm_name, int halo_num, int *bins, int lowbound_fac, int upbound_fac, int padding){
    //get shell
    char shell[10], shell1[10];
    sprintf(shell1, "_r%dto%d", lowbound_fac, upbound_fac); 
    sprintf(shell, "_r%dto%d", lowbound_fac, upbound_fac);  
    //sprintf(shell, "_c%dto%d_b1n2", lowbound_fac, upbound_fac);
    printf("for shell%s\n", shell);


    printf("initializing memory space\n");
    //file name, routes
    char in_halo_s[100], in_halo_g[100], in_halo_R[100], in_omega[100], in_halo_amp[100];

    sprintf(in_halo_s, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/pyout%s/gadg_u%s_halo_sls%s.dat", shell1, sim_num, sm_name); //fixedrad
    //sprintf(in_halo_s, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/pyout%s/gadg_u%s_halo_s%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(in_halo_g, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/pyout%s/gadg_u%s_halo_g%s.dat", shell1, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(in_halo_R, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/pyout%s/gadg_u%s_halo_R%s.dat", shell1, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(in_omega, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/pyout%s/gadg_u%s_halo_omega%s.dat", shell1, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(in_halo_amp, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/pyout%s/gadg_u%s_halo_ampsort%s.dat", shell1, sim_num, sm_name);

    char out_sfsb1[100], out_sfcb1[100], out_ufsb1[100], out_ufcb1[100];

    sprintf(out_sfsb1, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cossfsb1_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(out_sfcb1, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cossfcb1_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(out_ufsb1, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cosufsb1_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(out_ufcb1, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cosufcb1_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);

    char out_sfsb2[100], out_sfcb2[100], out_ufsb2[100], out_ufcb2[100];

    sprintf(out_sfsb2, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cossfsb2_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(out_sfcb2, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cossfcb2_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(out_ufsb2, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cosufsb2_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(out_ufcb2, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cosufcb2_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);

    char out_sfsb3[100], out_sfcb3[100], out_ufsb3[100], out_ufcb3[100];

    sprintf(out_sfsb3, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cossfsb3_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(out_sfcb3, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cossfcb3_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(out_ufsb3, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cosufsb3_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(out_ufcb3, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cosufcb3_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);

    char out_sfsb4[100], out_sfcb4[100], out_ufsb4[100], out_ufcb4[100];

    sprintf(out_sfsb4, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cossfsb4_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(out_sfcb4, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cossfcb4_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(out_ufsb4, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cosufsb4_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);
    sprintf(out_ufcb4, "../gadgetsim/halo_spinout/100Mpc/ampbin%s/gadg_u%s_halo_cosufcb4_%s.dat", shell, sim_num, sm_name);


    //array for recording
    float *cos_sfsb1, *cos_sfcb1, *cos_ufsb1, *cos_ufcb1;
    float *cos_sfsb2, *cos_sfcb2, *cos_ufsb2, *cos_ufcb2;
    float *cos_sfsb3, *cos_sfcb3, *cos_ufsb3, *cos_ufcb3;
    float *cos_sfsb4, *cos_sfcb4, *cos_ufsb4, *cos_ufcb4;
    
    cos_sfsb1 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);
    cos_sfcb1 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);
    cos_ufsb1 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);
    cos_ufcb1 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);

    cos_sfsb2 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);
    cos_sfcb2 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);
    cos_ufsb2 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);
    cos_ufcb2 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);

    cos_sfsb3 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);
    cos_sfcb3 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);
    cos_ufsb3 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);
    cos_ufcb3 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);

    cos_sfsb4 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);
    cos_sfcb4 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);
    cos_ufsb4 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);
    cos_ufcb4 = (float *) malloc(ngp*ngp*ngp*sizeof(float)/4);


    //initialize outputs
    for(int i=0; i<ngp*ngp*ngp/4; i++){
            cos_sfsb1[i] = -100;
            cos_sfcb1[i] = -100;
            cos_ufsb1[i] = -100;
            cos_ufcb1[i] = -100;

            cos_sfsb2[i] = -100;
            cos_sfcb2[i] = -100;
            cos_ufsb2[i] = -100;
            cos_ufcb2[i] = -100;

            cos_sfsb3[i] = -100;
            cos_sfcb3[i] = -100;
            cos_ufsb3[i] = -100;
            cos_ufcb3[i] = -100;

            cos_sfsb4[i] = -100;
            cos_sfcb4[i] = -100;
            cos_ufsb4[i] = -100;
            cos_ufcb4[i] = -100;
    }

    printf("reading halo data\n");
    float *halo_s, *halo_R;
    int *halo_g, *halo_amp;
    
    halo_s = (float *) malloc(3*halo_num*sizeof(float));
    //halo_s = (float *) malloc(3*ngp*ngp*ngp * sizeof(float));
    halo_g = (int *) malloc(3*halo_num*sizeof(int));
    halo_R = (float *) malloc(halo_num * sizeof(float));
    halo_amp = (int *) malloc(halo_num*sizeof(int));
    
    float *omega;
    omega = (float *) malloc(4*3*ngp*ngp*ngp * sizeof(float));
    
    FILE *F_halo_s, *F_halo_g, *F_halo_R, *F_halo_amp;
    FILE *F_omega;
    
    F_halo_s = fopen(in_halo_s, "rb");
    F_halo_g = fopen(in_halo_g, "rb");
    F_halo_R = fopen(in_halo_R, "rb");
    F_halo_amp = fopen(in_halo_amp, "rb");

    F_omega = fopen(in_omega, "rb");
    
    fread(halo_s, sizeof(float), 3*halo_num, F_halo_s);
    //fread(halo_s, sizeof(float), 3*ngp*ngp*ngp, F_halo_s);
    fread(halo_g, sizeof(int), 3*halo_num, F_halo_g);
    fread(halo_R, sizeof(float), halo_num, F_halo_R);
    fread(halo_amp, sizeof(int), halo_num, F_halo_amp);
    fread(omega, sizeof(float), 4*3*ngp*ngp*ngp, F_omega);
    
    printf("computing cosine...\n");

        //get physical radius mean
        float phy_R_mean=0;
    int g_R_mean=0;

    /*
        for(int i=0; i<bins[1]; i++){
        phy_R_mean = phy_R_mean + halo_R[i]; }
        phy_R_mean = phy_R_mean/bins[1];
        printf("%d, %f\n", bins[1], phy_R_mean); 
        //get mean radius in grid
        g_R_mean = phy_R_mean*ng/(1000*Lbox);
        if((phy_R_mean*ng/(1000*Lbox) - g_R_mean) > 0.5){
        g_R_mean += 1; }
    printf("mean of radius in grids: %f\n", g_R_mean);
    */

    /*
        h_spin_vor_fixedrad(halo_s, halo_g, g_R_mean, omega, 0, bins[0], halo_num, ng, Lbox, lowbound_fac, upbound_fac, padding, ngp, cos_sfsb1, cos_sfcb1, cos_ufsb1, cos_ufcb1);

        h_spin_vor_fixedrad(halo_s, halo_g, g_R_mean, omega, bins[0], bins[1], halo_num, ng, Lbox, lowbound_fac, upbound_fac, padding, ngp, cos_sfsb2, cos_sfcb2, cos_ufsb2, cos_ufcb2);
    */
    
    h_spin_vor_amp(halo_s, halo_amp, halo_g, halo_R, omega, 0, bins[0], halo_num, ng, Lbox, lowbound_fac, upbound_fac, padding, ngp, cos_sfsb1, cos_sfcb1, cos_ufsb1, cos_ufcb1);
    
    h_spin_vor_amp(halo_s, halo_amp, halo_g, halo_R, omega, bins[0], bins[1], halo_num, ng, Lbox, lowbound_fac, upbound_fac, padding, ngp, cos_sfsb2, cos_sfcb2, cos_ufsb2, cos_ufcb2);
    
    h_spin_vor_amp(halo_s, halo_amp, halo_g, halo_R, omega, bins[1], bins[2], halo_num, ng, Lbox, lowbound_fac, upbound_fac, padding, ngp, cos_sfsb3, cos_sfcb3, cos_ufsb3, cos_ufcb3);
    
    h_spin_vor_amp(halo_s, halo_amp, halo_g, halo_R, omega, bins[2], bins[3], halo_num, ng, Lbox, lowbound_fac, upbound_fac, padding, ngp, cos_sfsb4, cos_sfcb4, cos_ufsb4, cos_ufcb4);
    

    printf("computation done\n");
    free(halo_s);
    free(halo_g);
    free(halo_R);
    free(halo_amp);
    free(omega);

    printf("writing out the final data...\n");
    FILE *F_out_sfsb1, *F_out_sfcb1, *F_out_ufsb1, *F_out_ufcb1;
    FILE *F_out_sfsb2, *F_out_sfcb2, *F_out_ufsb2, *F_out_ufcb2;
    FILE *F_out_sfsb3, *F_out_sfcb3, *F_out_ufsb3, *F_out_ufcb3;
    FILE *F_out_sfsb4, *F_out_sfcb4, *F_out_ufsb4, *F_out_ufcb4;
    
    
    F_out_sfsb1 = fopen(out_sfsb1, "wb");
    F_out_sfcb1 = fopen(out_sfcb1, "wb");
    F_out_ufsb1 = fopen(out_ufsb1, "wb");
    F_out_ufcb1 = fopen(out_ufcb1, "wb");
    
    fwrite(cos_sfsb1, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_sfsb1);
    fwrite(cos_sfcb1, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_sfcb1);
    fwrite(cos_ufsb1, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_ufsb1);
    fwrite(cos_ufcb1, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_ufcb1);
    
    //free(cos_sfsb1), free(cos_sfcb1), free(cos_ufsb1), free(cos_ufcb1);

    
    F_out_sfsb2 = fopen(out_sfsb2, "wb");
    F_out_sfcb2 = fopen(out_sfcb2, "wb");
    F_out_ufsb2 = fopen(out_ufsb2, "wb");
    F_out_ufcb2 = fopen(out_ufcb2, "wb");
    
    fwrite(cos_sfsb2, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_sfsb2);
    fwrite(cos_sfcb2, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_sfcb2);
    fwrite(cos_ufsb2, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_ufsb2);
    fwrite(cos_ufcb2, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_ufcb2);
    
       //free(cos_sfsb2), free(cos_sfcb2), free(cos_ufsb2), free(cos_ufcb2);

/*  
    F_out_sfsb3 = fopen(out_sfsb3, "wb");
    F_out_sfcb3 = fopen(out_sfcb3, "wb");
    F_out_ufsb3 = fopen(out_ufsb3, "wb");
    F_out_ufcb3 = fopen(out_ufcb3, "wb");
    
    fwrite(cos_sfsb3, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_sfsb3);
    fwrite(cos_sfcb3, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_sfcb3);
    fwrite(cos_ufsb3, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_ufsb3);
    fwrite(cos_ufcb3, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_ufcb3);
    
        //free(cos_sfsb3), free(cos_sfcb3), free(cos_ufsb3), free(cos_ufcb3);

    
    F_out_sfsb4 = fopen(out_sfsb4, "wb");
    F_out_sfcb4 = fopen(out_sfcb4, "wb");
    F_out_ufsb4 = fopen(out_ufsb4, "wb");
    F_out_ufcb4 = fopen(out_ufcb4, "wb");
    
    fwrite(cos_sfsb4, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_sfsb4);
    fwrite(cos_sfcb4, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_sfcb4);
    fwrite(cos_ufsb4, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_ufsb4);
    fwrite(cos_ufcb4, sizeof(float), ngp*ngp*ngp/4, F_out_ufcb4);
    
        //free(cos_sfsb4), free(cos_sfcb4), free(cos_ufsb4), free(cos_ufcb4);
*/
}

int main()
{

//basic info of the set of simulations
float Lbox=100;
int ng=512;
int u0_halo_num=9946, u1_halo_num=9897, u2_halo_num=10380;
int u3_halo_num=9801, u4_halo_num=10062, u5_halo_num=10170;
int u6_halo_num=10028, u7_halo_num=10244, u8_halo_num=9925;
int u9_halo_num=10329, u10_halo_num=10168;

int bins[4];
int u0_bins[] = {8766, 9860, 9942, 9946}; //[  0.   0.1  0.2   0.3  0.4 ]
int u1_bins[] = {8770, 9812, 9892, 9897};
int u2_bins[] = {9270, 10282, 10371, 10380};
int u3_bins[] = {8645, 9720, 9799, 9801};
int u4_bins[] = {8862, 9966, 10061, 10062};
int u5_bins[] = {9023, 10074, 10164, 10170};
int u6_bins[] = {8884, 9924, 10021, 10027};
int u7_bins[] = {9119, 10156, 10236, 10244};
int u8_bins[] = {8849, 9848, 9923, 9925};
int u9_bins[] = {9213, 10240, 10321, 10329};
int u10_bins[] = {8984, 10073, 10159, 10168};

int lowbound_fac, bound_fac, padding0, padding1, padding2;
int padding3, padding4, padding5, padding6, padding7, padding8;
int padding9, padding10;
long ngp;
/*====================================*/


//control section
/*===============*/

//smoothing scale choice
char sm_name[] = "02";

//choose simulations
char sim_num[] = "0";
int sim_intnum = 0;
int halo_num = u0_halo_num;

for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
     bins[i] = u0_bins[i]; //change simulation number here too
}
printf("computing for u%s\n\n", sim_num);
/*============================*/


//compute for different shells

lowbound_fac=3, bound_fac=5, padding0=41, padding1=45, padding2=47;
padding3=54, padding4=49, padding5=35, padding6=37, padding7=47, padding8=48, padding9=47, padding10=51;

int padding_r3to5[] = {padding0, padding1, padding2, padding3, padding4, padding5,
            padding6, padding7, padding8, padding9, padding10};
ngp=ng+2*padding_r3to5[sim_intnum];

h_spin_shellwriter(Lbox, ng, ngp, sim_num, sm_name, halo_num, bins, lowbound_fac, bound_fac, padding_r3to5[sim_intnum]);


lowbound_fac=2, bound_fac=3, padding0=25, padding1=27, padding2=29;
padding3=33, padding4=30, padding5=21, padding6=23, padding7=29, padding8=29, padding9=29, padding10=31;

int padding_r2to3[] = {padding0, padding1, padding2, padding3, padding4, padding5,
                        padding6, padding7, padding8, padding9, padding10};
ngp=ng+2*padding_r2to3[sim_intnum];

h_spin_shellwriter(Lbox, ng, ngp, sim_num, sm_name, halo_num, bins, lowbound_fac, bound_fac, padding_r2to3[sim_intnum]);


lowbound_fac=1, bound_fac=2, padding0=17, padding1=18, padding2=19;
padding3=22, padding4=20, padding5=15, padding6=15, padding7=20, padding8=20, padding9=19, padding10=21;

int padding_r1to2[] = {padding0, padding1, padding2, padding3, padding4, padding5,
                        padding6, padding7, padding8, padding9, padding10};
ngp=ng+2*padding_r1to2[sim_intnum];

h_spin_shellwriter(Lbox, ng, ngp, sim_num, sm_name, halo_num, bins, lowbound_fac, bound_fac, padding_r1to2[sim_intnum]);

}
```

Comment: C is not script. Just one side note it's not valid to call C is script.  It's good to paste the source code also, then it ll help to know why your getting invalid write size.

Comment: Share the minified code which reproduce the issue

Comment: Thank you! I've updated my code(yeah not script)

Comment: @JoeXu - when debugging on *nix'es* compile with the `-g` option to enable `gdb` symbols -- which `valgrind` will use to output the line numbers in your code where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to help you exactly without any source code posted, but if you have problems understanding the valgrind output, it can be explained this way:

You've got a number of errors, each one in this form:

```
==21733== Invalid write of size 4
==21733==    at 0x4014A4: h_spin_vor_amp (in /mnt/scratch-            
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403104: h_spin_shellwriter (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403A2C: main (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==  Address 0x11c27208 is 0 bytes after a block of size 
209,584,584 alloc'd
==21733==    at 0x4C27A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==21733==    by 0x402954: h_spin_shellwriter (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403A2C: main (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
```

This means the following:

1. You allocated some memory (~200MB) using malloc from `h_spin_shellwriter`.
2. While executing code in `h_spin_vor_amp`:

   - you did a write of 4 bytes (uint32, an int on 32bit system, or something similar)
   - right after that allocated memory (`0 bytes after a block...`)

Most likely what happened was that you're iterating over all values in that allocated memory and went one too far. Or maybe you wanted to add something to the end of some array and didn't check whether there's any space left. Without any code, this is a most likely guess.

It could be a number of other issues however - accidentally overwriting some pointer, permanently increasing pointers instead of using temporary, or just doing bad offset calculation could also be the reasons.

The different error:

```
==21733== Invalid read of size 4
==21733==    at 0x400A30: h_spin_vor_amp (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403104: h_spin_shellwriter (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==    by 0x403A2C: main (in /mnt/scratch-
lustre/joexu/workplace/myC/halo_samp)
==21733==  Address 0xffffffff34cc3cdc is not stack'd, malloc'd or (r 
ecently) free'd
```

Indicates that you either accidentally saved a pointer to some memory which was later freed, or that you made a mistake in address calculation.

The curious thing is that you're not getting precise line information in the stacktrace. If you don't have debug information enabled when compiling, you should enable them. Otherwise, maybe removing optimisations will get you better answer.

Comment: Thank you. I add my code in this post. And how do I enable debug info when compiling/remove optimizations?

Comment: Oh also, could you tell me how do you know that I allocated ~200MB in the function from this valgrind report?

Comment: @JoeXu "after a block of size 209,584,584 alloc'd" means ~200MB.

Answer (score 0):

Where you uses `sprintf`, make sure the arrays parameters are null terminated.